# When using android:backround code my background doesn't change and remains the same

Tags: android, html, android-studio, android-layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    android:background="#fff092b0"> // HERE IS THE ERROR FOR COLOUR CHANGING!!!!!!
```

My colour is `android:background="#fff092b0"` but its not doing anything when i type the code. as seen from the screenshot its still white. [image]

Also i just want the emulator with the white background and not sure why the emulator with the blue background is present. How do i remove the second blue one? Thanks

I get the error Unexpected text found in layout file: `android:background="#fff092b0">` less... (Ctrl+F1) Inspection info:Layout resource files should only contain elements and attributes. Any XML text content found in the file is likely accidental (and potentially dangerous if the text resembles XML and the developer believes the text to be functional) Issue id: ExtraText

Also I am completely new to android studio and HTML so apologies for the noob questions as i am following a course from 2014 which seems to be slightly outdated.

Comment: `tools:context=".MainActivity">
android:background="#fff092b0"> `

It is probably for the `>` after MainActivity. There are two ending tags. Remove the `>` after MainActivity and check again.

Comment: Its so wierd when the answer is so simply and directly in front of me. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use 6 digits of hexadecimal number in order to represent a color. Such as your `#fffo92` represents **Yellow** and `#f092b0` represents **pink** colors. Try changing the number into 6 digits.

Comment: It is not correct.The extra 2 digits are used to define the alpha channel.